# About editing the jbutton in netbeans IDE

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

How to customize a code of JButton if  I design it by NetBeans ide 8.2, in Java GUI

Nothing is editable here even if I use custom properties

[image: Nothing is editable here even if I use custom properties.]

Comment: If you don't know how to use the IDE, it's a detriment, not a help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit e.g. the code for the `actionPerformed` event, you need to do that through the properties of the button:

[image]

Once you press enter or click the entry in the dropdown, you are taken to the editor, where you can customize the code of the event handler:

[image]

You can find more information in the [NetBeans manual](https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/run_java_guis.htm#NBDAG2619)

Comment: Actually I want to edit the ActionListener.If ActionPerformed is added, then ActionListener is automatically generated. Hence it can't be edited. My ultimate intention is to use swing timer in the JButton. thanks for your help though. It would be great if you could solve the problem for me.

Comment: The actionListener  **can** be edited as my screenshot clearly proves. You can do that from the properties of the control, not through some "code customizer"